# Solving difficult Lagrangian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = x - \lambda_1 ( - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + 2x-y) - \lambda_2 ( \frac{1}{2}x^2 -2x + 4 -y)
\end{equation}

This gives the following FOC's

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} & = 1 + \lambda_1x -2\lambda_1  - \lambda_2x + 2\lambda_2 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} & = \lambda_1  + \lambda_2 = 0 \\
y &= -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + 2x\\
 y &= \frac{1}{2}x^2 -2x + 4
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Here we have $-\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ substituting this into the first equation gives us

\begin{equation}
x = 2\lambda_1 - \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

Substituting this result into first constraint gives:

\begin{equation}
y = -2\lambda_1^ 2 + \frac{1}{8}
\end{equation}

substituting into the next constraint gives:

\begin{equation}
0 = 4\lambda_1^2 - 7/4 \lambda_1 + 71/16
\end{equation}

the last equation has no real roots so I cant solve the problem yet I know there should be a solution. Also I am not one 100% sure if I understand how to check for the second order conditions in this case. Could someone please help? Also, this Lagrangian should be also solvable using level curve method. Could someone explain me how that would work?

Comment: You have two constraints and two variables? This would mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is

$$
(\min,\max) x \ \ \mbox{s.t.}\ \ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}g_1(x,y) & = & -\frac 12 x^2 + 2x - y=0\\ g_2(x,y) & = & \frac 12 x^2-2x-y+4=0\end{array}\right.
$$

we have that $g_1(x,y)\cap g_2(x,y) = (2,2)$ so the feasible solution is at $x = 2$

Comment: Thanks, and how could be this solution found using level curves? Also how exactly one checks for second order conditions with multiple constraints?

Comment: @1muflon1 This problem is very peculiar. Both $g_1$ and $g_2$ are tangent, one  concave and other convex. A more general formulation could be with $g_1(x,y) = -x^2/2 + 2 x - y \le  0$ and $g_2(x,y) = x^2/2 - 2 x - y\ge 0$. In this case the feasible region is a convex set and  the  optimal conditions have full sense to apply.